# What is the purpose of overriding function in swift?

Tags: swift, function, overriding

It is very common the overriding syntax in swift code 
For example this code :

```
import UIKit

class PsychologistViewController: UIViewController {
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    }
}
```

Why i have to override this function to make segue , instead to use it directly ?

Comment: What do you mean "use it directly"?  You can use it directly.  You can't implement it without overriding it though because its parent class has implemented it.  Your question is confusing I think...

Comment: I am sorry about that i will work on my english

Comment: Although thanks you answered  my question